# How to make a product sell only as a bunch and not individually in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php

Hi Iam quite new to Magento i use Magento 1.8 CE, now i have a doubt i need to sell a product only as a set (for eg:- keyboard,monitor,mouse etc) whereas i sell keyboard,monitor and mouse individually too. Now if i want to sell my product only as a bunch (i.e) the user must not be able to select or buy any one or two of the products they must be only able to buy as a bunch.
Using grouped product option provides user to select products individually.

Please suggest me some option to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use bundle products.
Create a bundle product called "Some computer set" that has as bundle items keyboard, monitor and mouse, mandatory or not.
The products keyboard, monitor and mouse must be real products in your shop, but just set their visibility to 'Not visible individually'.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply i added a bundle product but it doesn't gets displayed in frontend i found that the product quatity is 0 but i don't have qty field to enter my quatity. In bundle items i added a new option and assigned two simple products to it but nothing gets displayed.please help me to update my quantity of products and where can i find the visibility option to make it not visible individually

Comment: You will find the option to make the simple products not visible individually by editing the simple products themselves. There is a field called `Visibility`. Also make sure that these simple products are in stock. When you are done configuring your bundle products, rebuild your indexes from system->index management.

Comment: i need to make only my bundle product not visible individually and not simple products.I changed the visibility for bundled product not visible individually and checked the quatity of my simple products and reindexed the data but no change, stil product is not visible in frontend and shows 0 qty.

Comment: You got it the other way around. Make the simple products not visible and the bundle one visible.

Comment: i want to sell keyboard,mouse etc individually as well as a bundle product.only in bundle product the user must not be able to select the products individually, if you make the keyboard or mouse not visible the product will not be displayed individually.I add two or more of my simple products together and sell it as a bundle.Is there any option inside bundle product configuration to make the product not visible individually.                      Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just now saw a video how to create a bundled product, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: How to make all the product in a bundle as mandatory??